# refer to Gradle task which is defined later in build

Tags: gradle

Our build has some generic logic to create tasks from configuration data. There are also several Gradle files on whose execution order I do not want to depend.

Now I need to add a task dependency to a task without knowing if that task will be defined before my part of the build script runs (at configuration time) or after my part.

[Edit: as @canillas writes I can say `myTask.dependsOn "otherTask"` and "lazily" depend on yet undefined "otherTask", but I need it the other way around.]

Since I can't write `tasks["otherTask"].dependsOn myNewTask` before "otherTask" is defined, I made the following helper function:

```java
void safelyDoWithTask(String taskName, Closure func) {
    def task = tasks.findByName(taskName)
    if (task != null) {
        func(task)
    } else {
        project.tasks.whenTaskAdded { task_ ->
            if (taskName.equals(task_.getName())) {
                func(task_)
            }
        }
    }
}

safelyDoWithTask('otherTask', { it.dependsOn myNewTask })
```

Now I wonder if there is more canonical way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies

Comment: Very good @canillas!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
// section 1
def dynamicDependencies = [:]

dynamicDependencies['otherTask'] = 'myNewTask'

// section 2
afterEvaluate { project ->
    // taskA dependsOn taskB
    dynamicDependencies.each { taskA, taskB ->
        def task = project.tasks.findByName(taskA)
        if (task) { task.dependsOn "${taskB}" }
    }
}

// section 3
task myNewTask() {
    doLast {
        println 'myNewTask !'
    }
}

task otherTask() {
    doLast {
        println 'otherTask !'
    }
}
```

The gist is:

- section 1 defines our dependency info in a custom map
- section 2 uses the `afterEvaluate` hook to process the map
- because the above is decoupled from the task definitions, we can simply put them in section 3 (or wherever)